# Assigning Output of nested SQL Query to a variable in bash Script

Tags: sql, bash

I want to get the output of the following nested query into a variable in the bash script as follows.

```
count=SELECT count(*) FROM a
WHERE TRIM(REQUEST_STATUS) IN ('d','e','v') AND
(abc IS NULL) AND EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM n WHERE LOWER(NAME)=LOWER(a.LOGINNAME)));
```

please help.

Comment: Use a cmd line client of your choice - you do not tell us which database is concerned - and the backtick to get the output into a bash variable. See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/27428/what-does-backquote-backtick-mean-in-commands for backtick.

Comment: You also don't tell us where your script is and where your database is.  Nonetheless, I must candidly say that the *easiest* way to get this done would be to use a scripting language other than Bash.  For instance, if the first line of your command file was, say, `#!/usr/bin/php`, then the shell would silently use PHP to handle your script ... now written in PHP ... and the end-user would be none the wiser.  The built-in scripting of Bash is very primitive, and attempts like this one to make it do things it wasn't designed for get VERY messy VERY fast.

Comment: Assuming you know what client you want to use, this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/4651437/1126841. However, unless your query really is static and you aren't try to parameterize it, `bash` is the wrong language in which to be constructing dynamic queries.